# call another action with other request body

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

I try to write an action that calls several other actions of other controllers. Those actions expect a JSON as request body:

```
JsonNode jsonNode = request().body().asJson();
```

How can I call another action with a specific request body (JSON)?

**Restriction:** I can not modify the other controllers.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: My action simulates a special kind of client. The real client does some requests that I have to simulate in my action.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the **Reverse Routing** feature of play, get a `Call` to the destination `Action Method`, convert it to a url and use the `WSClient` in order to send your request. In scala, say you're gonna send a `POST` request to an action method in `Application` controller named `index`:

```
val url = routes.Application.index().absoluteURL
wsClient.url(url).post[JsValue](json)
```

Same ideas apply to Java API but i'm not quite familiar with the details

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I think this should do the trick. This version is for scala, I am not familiar with Play Java.

```
def actionJson: Action[JsValue] = Action(parse.json) { request =>
  Ok("json body")
}

def actionAny: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { request =>
  actionJson(request.map(_.asJson)).run
}
```